# Logitech c310 with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: webcam, logitech, camera

I am currently trying to use my Logitech c310 camera with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS but have gotten no where with it. I have built and installed the uvc drivers. All i need to do is take a picture any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the camera was working but the light was not.
Thanks for anyone who was working on an answer.